# Fail to create couponbonds object in termstrc package using R

Tags: r

I am trying to use R package termstrc to estimate the term structure. To do that I have to prepare the data as the couponbonds class required by the package. I used some fake data to prevent the potential problem of the real data. Though I tried a lot, it still didn't work. 
Any idea what is going wrong?

structure of the official demo data which works

```
data("govbonds")
str(govbonds)

List of 3
$ GERMANY:List of 8
..$ ISIN        : chr [1:52] "DE0001141414" "DE0001137131" "DE0001141422" "DE0001137149" ...
..$ MATURITYDATE: Date[1:52], format: "2008-02-15" "2008-03-14" "2008-04-11" ...
..$ ISSUEDATE   : Date[1:52], format: "2002-08-14" "2006-03-08" "2003-04-11" ...
..$ COUPONRATE  : num [1:52] 0.0425 0.03 0.03 0.0325 0.0413 ...
..$ PRICE       : num [1:52] 100 99.9 99.8 99.8 100.1 ...
..$ ACCRUED     : num [1:52] 4.09 2.66 2.43 2.07 2.39 ...
..$ CASHFLOWS   :List of 3
.. ..$ ISIN: chr [1:384] "DE0001141414" "DE0001137131" "DE0001141422" "DE0001137149" ...
.. ..$ CF  : num [1:384] 104 103 103 103 104 ...
.. ..$ DATE: Date[1:384], format: "2008-02-15" "2008-03-14" "2008-04-11" ...
..$ TODAY       : Date[1:1], format: "2008-01-30"
#another two are omitted here
- attr(*, "class")= chr "couponbonds"
> ns_res <- estim_nss(govbonds, c("GERMANY"), method = "ns",tauconstr=list(c(0.2, 5, 0.1)))
[1] "Searching startparameters for  GERMANY"
beta0     beta1     beta2      tau1 
5.008476 -1.092510 -3.209695  2.400100
```

my code to prepare fake data

```
bond=list()
bond$CHINA=list()
n=30*12#suppose I have n bond
enddate=as.Date('2014/11/7')
isin=sprintf('DE%010d',1:n)#some fake ISIN
bond$CHINA$ISIN=isin
bond$CHINA$MATURITYDATE=enddate+(1:n)*30
bond$CHINA$ISSUEDATE=rep(enddate,n)
bond$CHINA$COUPONRATE=rep(5/100,n)
bond$CHINA$PRICE=rep(100,n)
bond$CHINA$ACCRUED=rep(0,n)
bond$CHINA$CASHFLOWS=list()
bond$CHINA$CASHFLOWS$ISIN=isin
bond$CHINA$CASHFLOWS$CF=100+(1:n)*5/12
bond$CHINA$CASHFLOWS$DATE=enddate+(1:n)*30
bond$CHINA$TODAY=enddate
class(bond)='couponbonds'
ns_res <- estim_nss(bond, c("CHINA"), method = "ns",tauconstr=list(c(0.2, 5, 0.1)))
```

the output

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("DE0000000001", "DE0000000002",  : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was finally solved by adding one cashflow with amount zero to the `CASHFLOW$CF`.
Put it in another way, at least one bond should have at least two cashflows.
Then you may face another error caused by `uniroot` function. Be sure to only include the cashflow after `TODAY`. The `termstrc` doesn't filter the cashflow for you by using `TODAY`.